H2 Database Fails on ALTER TABLE with Multiple Columns Despite PostgreSQL Compatibility Mode
I'm facing an issue when running integration tests with H2 using SQL scripts via JDBC. I have an ALTER TABLE SQL query that works perfectly on my PostgreSQL database in the development environment, but it fails when running tests with H2.
The query is:

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN c1 VARCHAR, ADD COLUMN c2 VARCHAR;


It seems that H2 doesn't accept adding multiple columns in a single ALTER TABLE statement, whereas PostgreSQL has no issue with it.
I've already added the following configuration to enable PostgreSQL compatibility mode in H2:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1


However, this hasn't resolved the problem. Is there any other setting or solution I can apply to make this query work in my H2 tests without modifying the SQL script?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I added the following configuration to enable PostgreSQL compatibility mode in H2:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1


I expected this to allow H2 to accept the ALTER TABLE statement with multiple columns, just like PostgreSQL does. However, H2 still fails with a syntax error, and I can't modify the SQL script itself.

Some DBMS have special non-standard syntax that allows addition of multiple columns at once, but this syntax in not really portable across various systems. Oracle and H2 use the same syntax, PostgreSQL and MySQL use another syntax and so on.

What database do you use in production? Develop and test on that one. If you support multiple brands you have to write generic code that is supported by all


Go here H2 and search for PostgreSQL Compatibility Mode on the page. That will show what is supported, spoiler multiple columns is not. 2) Bottom line test against the database you are deploying to.


@FrankHeikens We use PostgreSQL in our development and production environments, and H2/PostgreSQL for testing. However, we encounter an issue with certain system tables, like information_schema.tables, because H2 treats information_schema as a database schema rather than a system table. This causes difficulties during test execution.

Advice: Throw away H2. The test results are useless since your target is PostgreSQL.
